# .htaccess Redirecting url to a folder. Error on loading resources

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect from URL to a folder.
So, in the htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.org/portal/$1 [P]
```

But, when the portal app is requested it calls many .css .js .png files...
When these files are requesteds, the URL works like this:

```
www.example.com/portal/file1.css
www.example.com/portal/file2.js...
```

and I receive the 404(file not found)

It because when the app requests the files, the htaccess intercepts the call and reirect it to `www.example.com/portal/portal/file1.css`

So, i need when the exactly domain www.example.com is called, the rule redirect to `www.example.com/portal`. But when some resource of portal be called, the redirect must be do to `www.example.com/resource`. Internally it working like: `www.example.com/portal/portal` and i receive the 404 error

Help-me please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're using a relative path to your assets `href="/portal/file.css"` and the root url is `www.example.com/portal`

Try using the links without directory like `href="/file.css"`